# Where can I find a blog-style case study of juju workflow

Tags: juju

So I've skimmed all the introductory juju docs and I still don't really understand what exactly juju is. I'm aware that this is a very vague complaint but I don't yet have a clear enough picture of what juju is to ask a specific question.

I'm still quite interested in understanding what juju is, so can anyone point me to either (1) a case study of how some company uses juju and what other tools they use in tandem, (2) an explanation of juju that places it in context by comparing what it does to other nearby things in the ecosystem (puppet, docker, kubernetes, etc), or (3) a concrete description of what juju does "under the hood"?